# I want to refresh my jsp page on the click of radiobutton

Tags: jquery

I want to refresh my jsp page on the click of radiobutton without refreshing the click of radio button.

Comment: Be clear on your question..add some code pieces. and don't ask open ended questions. see the faq of stackoverflow @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Please paste some code, where you found any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to refresh your page and get the same radio button clicked after refresh, you'd have to restore it :

```
$(function(){
    // restoration :
    var clicked = localStorage['clicked'];
    if (clicked) $('input:radio[name="'+clicked'"]').attr('checked',true);

   // save and refresh :
   $('input:radio').click(function(){
       localStorage['clicked'] = this.name;
       location.reload();
   }
});
```